# C++ - Should argv[] in the int main be always of the type char* (or char** if argv is used)?

Tags: c++, char, command-line-arguments, program-entry-point

I understand that since `argc` is the number of arguments, it can be an int. But why should `argv` be of `char pointer` type? Does this mean I cannot pass an integer argument and use `argv[1]` in mathematical operations?

**Edit**: To make it more clear, is it possible to write something like `int* argv[]` . Is `argv` already defined as `char*` type such that it cannot be changed?

Comment: Look into `atoi`.

Comment: Actually my intention is to know if there is any way to pass the integer (or types other than char) argument from command line and use them directly without using `atoi`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually there are two valid definitions for `main`:

```
int main() { /* ... */ }
```

and

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) { /* ... */ }
```

or equivalent. (Note that, as a parameter, `char *argv[]` is equivalent to `char **argv`, which is a more accurate representation of what it is, a pointer to pointer to `char`.)

Implementations can, but are not required to, support other forms; for example some systems support an additional `char *envp[]` parameter.

What's unusual about `main` isn't that it doesn't have just a single valid definition. It's that, unlike other user-defined functions, it doesn't have infinitely many. For example, you can define a function named `foo` any way you like. The definition of `main` is restricted because it's your program's entry point, and the calling environment has to know how to call it.

This is covered in more detail in section 3.6.1 of the ISO C++ standard. [N4296](http://open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/n4296.pdf) is a draft of the 2014 edition.

If you want to pass integers as command-line arguments, pass them as strings and then parse them.  (The `atoi()` function is one of the simplest ways to do this, but it doesn't do any error checking. The `std::stoi()` function, defined in the `<string>` header starting with C++11, is better.)

The `main` function takes a list of strings (strictly speaking a `char**` pointer to the initial element of an array of `char*` pointers, each of which points to the beginning of a string) because it's an extremely flexible data structure and yet it isn't overly complicated. (Note that a "string" here is a C-style string, a sequence of characters terminated by a `'\0'` null character -- not to be confused with the `std::string` type defined by the C++ standard library.)

There are various open-source libraries for parsing command-line arguments. For example, Unix-like systems have a `getopt()` function; see its documentation for more details.

See also [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3024197/827263).

Comment: This part was helpful, "What's unusual about main isn't that it doesn't have just a single valid definition. It's that, unlike other user-defined functions, it doesn't have infinitely many." Also, thank you for the additional info.

Comment: @Schwern: The OP is asking about C++, not C (mentioned in the title; I just added the tag). There are some differences between C and C++ in this area.

Comment: if you're going to qualify something as "strictly speaking", take care to get it right.   The `argv` argument is not a "pointer to an array of pointers to strings".

Comment: @Peter: Good point. The C standard defines a "pointer to a string" as a pointer to the initial character of the string (where a "string" is defined as "a contiguous sequence of characters terminated by and including the first null character"). C++ doesn't seem to have a similar definition for a "pointer to a string".